# Biblio module: importing ris files, titles not importing even though mapped correctly

Tags: importing-exporting

I have ris files of citations to upload, and despite having titles mapped correctly at admin/config/content/biblio/iomap/edit/ris -- T1 goes to Title, I get nothing but "untitled" nodes. I am using version 7.x-1.0-rc7. Some other data seems to populate appropriately, but looking at logs, many things aren't, so it's more than just titles. I have a large number of errors for a number of fields along the lines of:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$title in _biblio_ris_parse_line() (line 357 of C:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\biblio\modules\RIS\biblio_ris.module).
```

Thinking there might be something wrong with the data, I created my own simple ris file and tried an example file that I found online. I had the same problems with all of them.

I tried the dev version and have the same problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

after finding [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/2361155#comment-9790731), I changed two lines in biblio_ris.module:

339 from

```
$node->biblio_pages .= ($tag == "SP") ? $data : " - " . $data;
```

to

```
$node->biblio_pages = ($tag == "SP") ? $data : " - " . $data;
```

and 357, from:

```
$node->$field .= $data;
```

to

```
$node->$field = $data;
```

It works.